# Android Pinch Zoom ImageView (PhotoView) with ScrollView

Tags: android, imageview

I have the following layout in android where I basically have an image view with a composite caption consisted of other imageviews+textviews:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/imagePager_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
                android:id="@+id/imagePager_imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imagePager_textTitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="TITLE"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imagePager_imageView"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imagePager_titleLine"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/imagePager_textTitle"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                   android:paddingRight="5dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/linebig"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imagePager_textSubtitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="SUBTITLE"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imagePager_titleLine"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imagePager_subtitleLine"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/imagePager_textSubtitle"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                   android:paddingRight="30dp"
                   android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/linebig"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imagePager_textContent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="CONTENT"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imagePager_subtitleLine"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The issue is that if the entire content is so "long" that the `ScrollView` is enabled then `Pinch Zoom` doesnt work. Else it works perfectly. I guess the ScrollView listeners considers the "Pinch" and up/down motion. Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

change your scrollview to android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView